Given a Maximum Likelihood Estimator and Poisson Distribution, how do I calculate the bias?
I have a question about calculating the bias.
I have a MLE for parameter theta:
$
\hat{\theta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}
$
$ i  {\in} {1,2,.., n} $
where we have a Poisson model with data $y_i$ observed at locations $i = 1, 2, ..., n $
$y_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\theta x_i)$
How do I calculate the bias which is defined as:
$\text{Bias}(\hat{\theta}) = \mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}] - \theta
 $
So I try to substitute $ \hat{\theta} $ into the bias formula above, which results in:
$\text{Bias}(\hat{\theta}) = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}\right] - {\theta } $
How do I check if the bias of the MLE is zero after this step? I'm not too sure how to simplify the expression after substituting it in.

For computing the expected value, note that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum_i y_i}{\sum_i x_i}\right]=\frac{1}{\sum x_i}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_i  y_i\right]=\frac{1}{\sum_i x_i}\sum_i\mathbb{E}[y_i]=\frac{1}{\sum_i x_i}\sum_i \theta x_i = \theta$$ where we use that $\frac{1}{\sum_ix_i}$ is a constant, that the expectation is linear and that each Poisson random variable $y_i$ has mean equal to its parameter $\theta x_i$.
Thus $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum_i y_i}{\sum_i x_i}\right] - \theta =0$ as desired.

why does the E[yi] become a theta xi?

Because the expected value of a Poisson random variable is precisely its parameter. In this case, since $y_i\sim \text{Poisson}(\theta x_i)$, you get $\mathbb{E}[y_i]=\theta x_i$.
